# PropertyChanged for indexer property

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, indexer

I have a class with an indexer property, with a string key:

```
public class IndexerProvider {
    public object this[string key] {
        get
        {
            return ...
        }
        set
        {
            ...
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

I bind to an instance of this class in WPF, using indexer notation:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding [IndexerKeyThingy]}">
```

That works fine, but I want to raise a `PropertyChanged` event when one of the indexer values changes. I tried raising it with a property name of "[keyname]" (i.e. including [] around the name of the key), but that doesn't seem to work. I don't get binding errors in my output window whatsoever.

I can't use CollectionChangedEvent, because the index is not integer based. And technically, the object isn't a collection anyway.

Can I do this, and so, how?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

According to [this blog entry](https://web.archive.org/web/20100127102448/http://blogs.msdn.com/xtof/archive/2007/09/28/binding-to-indexers.aspx), you have to use `"Item[]"`. Item being the name of the property generated by the compiler when using an indexer.

If you want to be explicit, you can decorate the indexer property with an [IndexerName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.indexernameattribute.aspx) attribute.

That would make the code look like:

```
public class IndexerProvider : INotifyPropertyChanged {

    [IndexerName ("Item")]
    public object this [string key] {
        get {
            return ...;
        }
        set {
            ... = value;
            FirePropertyChanged ("Item[]");
        }
    }
}
```

At least it makes the intent more clear. I don't suggest you change the indexer name though, if your buddy found the string `"Item[]"` hard coded, it probably means that WPF would not be able to deal with a different indexer name.

Comment: That works great. Strange that I missed that blogpost in my Google searches.

Comment: This solution works great, but it has an annoying limitation: you can't specify that the value changed only for one key... So if you have bindings on many keys, they will all be refreshed

Comment: A few years later, now there's the 'nameof' keyword. I use that for all my `FirePropertyChange` calls, but can you `nameof` the indexer in any way?

Comment: Not sure what is implemented in `FirePropertyChanged` but using `OnPropertyChanged("Item")` is the only working code at least in *Xamarin Forms*. Not sure why it is so troublesome with the appending `[]`.

Comment: You should use Binding.IndexerName (https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.binding.indexername) instead of hard coding "Item[]"

Answer (score 18):

Additionaly, you can use

```
FirePropertyChanged ("Item[IndexerKeyThingy]");
```

To notify only controls bound to IndexerKeyThingy on your indexer.

Comment: +1 Useful to know you can raise it per dictionary entry

Comment: Has anyone successfully gotten this to work? It isn't working for me. Only "Item[]" seems to trigger updates.

Comment: It works fine on Silverlight 4/5, but on WPF 4.6.2 it doesn't work at all. Still have to use Item[].

Comment: That's a discrete `INotifyCollectionChanged` behavior! I would wonder if that's gonna work in Xamarin.Forms.

Comment: How is it like in multidimensional arrays?

Comment: It works perfectly on Xamarin Forms for me, at least in 2023 v5.x!

Answer (score 9):

There are at least a couple of additional caveats when dealing with INotifyPropertyChang(ed/ing) and indexers.

The first is that most of the [popular methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1315621/) of avoiding magic property name strings are ineffective. The string created by the [`[CallerMemberName]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) attribute is missing the '[]' at the end, and lambda member expressions have problems expressing the concept at all.

```
() => this[]  //Is invalid
() => this[i] //Is a method call expression on get_Item(TIndex i)
() => this    //Is a constant expression on the base object
```

Several [other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6338627/1848719) [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4964858/1848719) have used [`Binding.IndexerName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.indexername%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to avoid the string literal `"Item[]"`, which is reasonable, but raises the second potential issue. An investigation of the dissasembly of related parts of WPF turned up the following segment in PropertyPath.ResolvePathParts.

```
if (this._arySVI[i].type == SourceValueType.Indexer)
  {
    IndexerParameterInfo[] array = this.ResolveIndexerParams(this._arySVI[i].paramList, obj, throwOnError);
    this._earlyBoundPathParts[i] = array;
    this._arySVI[i].propertyName = "Item[]";
  }
```

The repeated use of `"Item[]"` as a constant value suggests that WPF is expecting that to be the name passed in the PropertyChanged event, and, even if it doesn't care what the actual property is called (which I didn't determine to my satisfaction one way or the other), avoiding use of `[IndexerName]` would maintain consistency.

Answer (score 5):

Actually, I believe setting the IndexerName attribute to "Item" is redundant.  The IndexerName attribute is specifically designed to rename an index, if you want to give it's collection item a different name.  So your code could look something like this:

```
public class IndexerProvider : INotifyPropertyChanged {

    [IndexerName("myIndexItem")]
    public object this [string key] {
        get {
            return ...;
        }
        set {
            ... = value;
            FirePropertyChanged ("myIndexItem[]");
        }
    }
}
```

Once you set the indexer name to whatever you want, you can then use it in the FirePropertyChanged event.