# Bind custom method with parameters in ViewModel

Tags: c#, mvvm, parameters, uwp, routed-events

I am creating a UWP MVVM app. I have created ViewModel and View, I make it DataContext, and everything is working just fine with bindings.

I was able to invoke method that has no parameters. This is my XAML code in View:

```
<Button VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="50" Width="50" Height="50" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent" Content="OK" FontSize="32" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="White" Click="{x:Bind Path=ViewModel.ButtonMainClick, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

In ViewModel I have like this:

```
public void ButtonMainClick()
{
    // TO DO
}
```

And this works just fine.

Now I want to invoke some method that has parameters. But I am unable to do it this way. I saw on internet that there is a EventTriggerBehavior. But I am not sure how to use it and pass some parameters.

Any idea?

Comment: Are the parameter values always the same, or do they depend on other values / controls?

Comment: Parameters are from Enum that I defined.

Comment: But are you always passing the same value?

Comment: Yes, like this: ButtonMainClickEvent?.Invoke(Model.ControlTypeEnum);

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that UWP and WPF binding work the same, you should bind your buttons to properties of type `ICommand` in your `ViewModel`. A common implementation of `ICommand` is the `RelayCommand`, which could look like this:

```
 public class RelayCommand : ICommand
    {
        private readonly Action _targetExecuteMethod;
        private readonly Func<bool> _targetCanExecuteMethod;
        public RelayCommand(Action executeMethod) => _targetExecuteMethod = executeMethod;

        public RelayCommand(Action executeMethod, Func<bool> canExecuteMethod)
        {
            _targetExecuteMethod = executeMethod;
            _targetCanExecuteMethod = canExecuteMethod;
        }
        public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged() => CanExecuteChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        bool ICommand.CanExecute(object parameter) => _targetCanExecuteMethod?.Invoke() ?? _targetExecuteMethod != null;
        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged = delegate { };
        void ICommand.Execute(object parameter) => _targetExecuteMethod?.Invoke();
    }
    public class RelayCommand<T> : ICommand
    {
        private readonly Action<T> _targetExecuteMethod;
        private readonly Func<T, bool> _targetCanExecuteMethod;
        public RelayCommand(Action<T> executeMethod) => _targetExecuteMethod = executeMethod;
        public RelayCommand(Action<T> executeMethod, Func<T, bool> canExecuteMethod)
        {
            _targetExecuteMethod = executeMethod;
            _targetCanExecuteMethod = canExecuteMethod;
        }
        public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged() => CanExecuteChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        bool ICommand.CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            if (_targetCanExecuteMethod != null)
            {
                var tparm = (T)parameter;
                return _targetCanExecuteMethod(tparm);
            }
            return _targetExecuteMethod != null;
        }
        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged = delegate { };
        void ICommand.Execute(object parameter) => _targetExecuteMethod?.Invoke((T)parameter);
    }
```

For the View and ViewModel, take a look at this example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53045098/9889260

If you want to use parameters. You just use the generic `RelayCommand<T>` where `T` is the type you want to pass as a parameter and also give your `Excecute` and `CanExcecute`(if you have one) methods `T` as your parameter.

Kind regards,
mis

Answer (score 0):

Event handlers using `x:Bind` can't take arbitrary arguments.

One simple solution is just to expose another method that makes the call for you. The method bound to the `Click` event has no parameters, but it just calls the method you need to execute.

[Edit] If you need to pass context from the control that generated the event, you can do that by adding the event signature and accessing the `sender`'s `DataContext` and casting your ViewModel type.

```
void FuncThatDoesSomething(T1 arg1, T2 arg2,...)
{
  // do it
}

// function has to match the event handler signature 
void FuncThatIsBoundInXaml(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  var vm = sender.DataContext as YourViewModelType;
  // call method with required args
  FuncThatDoesSomething(vm.SomeProperty, 42);
}
```

Comment: But each item in ListView that use this event has different value in that Enum.

Comment: Hence the question above about whether it was constant or not :-). Is there anything about the control that lets you know which enum value to pass?

Comment: Well, each item have Model, and in that model the EnumType is calculated based on some other parameter. The model itself of each item have that information. :)

Comment: <ItemsControl Name="lvItems" ItemsSource="{x:Bind Path=ViewModel.Model.ListItems, Mode=OneWay}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTemplate}"/>

<DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate" x:DataType="data:GlobalListItem">
  <Controls:ListItemControl Model="{x:Bind Mode=OneWay}"/>
</DataTemplate>

Comment: Was the button contained in your ListViewItem? Maybe, you post a [mcve], then, we could help you more.