# Picker not showing the previous value on update page

Tags: c#, maui

I have a problem with the Picker control in .NET MAUI. On the update page, the picker is not showing the value of update model.
Here is how is picker defined in the xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiUI.Pages.AddOrUpdatePlayer"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Backend.Models;assembly=Backend.Models"
             xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit">

    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <local:PlayerModel x:Name="ViewModel"/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem IconImageSource="save.svg" Clicked="OnSaveClick" Command="{Binding ValidateCommand}">
        </ToolbarItem>
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>

    <ScrollView Margin="10">
        <VerticalStackLayout>
            <VerticalStackLayout>
                <Label Text="Name" />
                <Entry x:Name="name" Text="{Binding Name}"
                       ClearButtonVisibility="WhileEditing">
                    <Entry.Behaviors>
                        <toolkit:EventToCommandBehavior
                            EventName="TextChanged"
                            Command="{Binding [Name].HasError}" />
                    </Entry.Behaviors>
                </Entry>
                <Label x:Name="lblValidationErrorName" Text="{Binding [Name].Error}" TextColor="Red" />
            </VerticalStackLayout>
            <VerticalStackLayout Margin="0,10">
                <Label Text="Position" />
                <Picker x:Name="position" Title="Select..."
                        ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Name}"
                        SelectedItem="{Binding Position}">
                </Picker>
                <Label x:Name="lblValidationErrorPosition" TextColor="red" Text="{Binding [Position].Error}"/>
            </VerticalStackLayout>
            <VerticalStackLayout Margin="0,10">
                <Label Text="Club" />
                <Entry x:Name="club" Text="{Binding Club}" 
                       ClearButtonVisibility="WhileEditing">
                    <Entry.Behaviors>
                        <toolkit:EventToCommandBehavior
                            EventName="TextChanged"
                            Command="{Binding [Club].HasError}" />
                    </Entry.Behaviors>
                </Entry>
                <Label x:Name="lblValidationErrorClub" TextColor="red" Text="{Binding [Club].Error}"/>
            </VerticalStackLayout>
            <VerticalStackLayout Margin="0,10">
                <Label Text="Birthday" />
                <DatePicker  x:Name="birthday" Date="{Binding Birthday}"/>
            </VerticalStackLayout>
            <VerticalStackLayout Margin="0,10">
                <Label Text="Birth place" />
                <Entry x:Name="birthplace" Text="{Binding BirthPlace}" 
                       ClearButtonVisibility="WhileEditing">
                    <Entry.Behaviors>
                        <toolkit:EventToCommandBehavior
                            EventName="TextChanged"
                            Command="{Binding [BirthPlace].HasError}" />
                    </Entry.Behaviors>
                </Entry>
                <Label x:Name="lblValidationErrorBirthPlace" TextColor="red" Text="{Binding [BirthPlace].Error}"/>
            </VerticalStackLayout>
            <VerticalStackLayout Margin="0,10">
                <Label Text="Weight" />
                <Entry x:Name="weight" Text="{Binding Weight}"
                       ClearButtonVisibility="WhileEditing" Keyboard="Numeric">
                    <Entry.Behaviors>
                        <toolkit:EventToCommandBehavior
                            EventName="TextChanged"
                            Command="{Binding [Weight].HasError}" />
                    </Entry.Behaviors>
                </Entry>
                <Label x:Name="lblValidationErrorWeight" TextColor="red" Text="{Binding [Weight].Error}" />
            </VerticalStackLayout>
            <VerticalStackLayout Margin="0,10">
                <Label Text="Height" />
                <Entry x:Name="height" Text="{Binding Height}" 
                       ClearButtonVisibility="WhileEditing" Keyboard="Numeric">
                    <Entry.Behaviors>
                        <toolkit:EventToCommandBehavior
                            EventName="TextChanged"
                            Command="{Binding [Height].HasError}" />
                    </Entry.Behaviors>
                </Entry>
                <Label x:Name="lblValidationErrorHeight" TextColor="red" Text="{Binding [Height].Error}" />
            </VerticalStackLayout>
            <VerticalStackLayout Margin="0,10">
                <Label Text="Image link" />
                <Entry x:Name="webImageLink" Text="{Binding WebImageLink}"
                       ClearButtonVisibility="WhileEditing">
                    <Entry.Behaviors>
                        <toolkit:EventToCommandBehavior
                            EventName="TextChanged"
                            Command="{Binding [WebImageLink].HasError}" />
                    </Entry.Behaviors>
                </Entry>
                <Label x:Name="lblValidationErrorWebImageLink" TextColor="red" Text="{Binding [WebImageLink].Error}"/>
            </VerticalStackLayout>
            <VerticalStackLayout Margin="0,10">
                <Label Text="Description" />
                <Editor x:Name="description" Text="{Binding Description}"
                        AutoSize="TextChanges">
                    <Editor.Behaviors>
                        <toolkit:EventToCommandBehavior
                            EventName="TextChanged"
                            Command="{Binding [Description].HasError}" />
                    </Editor.Behaviors>
                </Editor>
                <Label x:Name="lblValidationErrorDescription" TextColor="red" Text="{Binding [Description].Error}"/>
            </VerticalStackLayout>
        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage>
```

The code behind:

```
[QueryProperty(nameof(Player), "player")]
public partial class AddOrUpdatePlayer : ContentPage
{
    private PlayerModel player;
    public PlayerModel Player
    {
        get => player;
        set
        {
            player = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("player");
        }
    }

    private readonly IMemoryCache memoryCache;
    private readonly IPlayerClient playerClient;


    private delegate Task Action();
    private Action asyncAction;


    public AddOrUpdatePlayer(IMemoryCache memoryCache, IPlayerClient playerClient)
    {
        this.memoryCache = memoryCache;
        this.playerClient = playerClient;

        InitializeComponent();
        SetUpPositionPicker();
    }

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        player ??= new PlayerModel();
        player.ValidationCompleted += OnValidationHandler;

        BindingContext = player;

        SetUpControls();
        SetTitle();
        SetActionPointer();
    }

    private void SetUpControls()
    {
        birthday.MinimumDate = new DateTime(1900, 1, 1);
        birthday.MaximumDate = DateTime.Now.Date;

        memoryCache.TryGetValue(CacheKeys.Positions, out List<PositionModel> positions);
        var selectedPosition = positions.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == player?.Position?.Id);
        var index = positions.IndexOf(selectedPosition);
        position.SelectedIndex = index;
    }

    private void SetUpPositionPicker()
    {
        memoryCache.TryGetValue(CacheKeys.Positions, out List<PositionModel> positions);
        position.ItemsSource = positions;
    }

    private void SetTitle()
    {
        Title = this.player?.Id == 0 ?
                "Add new player" :
                $"Update {player?.Name}";
    }

    private void SetActionPointer()
    {
        asyncAction = this.player?.Id == 0 ?
                      AddNewPlayer :
                      UpdatePlayer;
    }

    private async Task AddNewPlayer()
    {
        var result = await playerClient.CreateAsync(player);

        if (!result)
            return;
    }

    private async Task UpdatePlayer()
    {
        var result = await playerClient.UpdateAsync(player);

        if (!result)
            return;
    }

    private async void OnSaveClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (player?.HasErrors ?? true)
            return;

        await asyncAction();
    }

    private void OnValidationHandler(Dictionary<string, string?> validationMessages)
    {
        if (validationMessages is null)
            return;

        lblValidationErrorName.Text = validationMessages.GetValueOrDefault("name");
        lblValidationErrorPosition.Text = validationMessages.GetValueOrDefault("positionid");
        lblValidationErrorClub.Text = validationMessages.GetValueOrDefault("club");
        lblValidationErrorWebImageLink.Text = validationMessages.GetValueOrDefault("webimagelink");
        lblValidationErrorBirthPlace.Text = validationMessages.GetValueOrDefault("birthplace");
        lblValidationErrorWeight.Text = validationMessages.GetValueOrDefault("weight");
        lblValidationErrorHeight.Text = validationMessages.GetValueOrDefault("height");
        lblValidationErrorDescription.Text = validationMessages.GetValueOrDefault("description");
    }
}

public partial class PlayerModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private int id;
    private string name;
    private string webImageLink;
    private string club;
    private string birthday;
    private string birthPlace;
    private int? weight;
    private double? height;
    private string description;
    private PositionModel position;
    
    public int Id
    {
        get => this.id;
        set => SetProperty(ref this.id, value, true);
    }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(255)]
    [MinLength(2)]
    public string Name
    {
        get => this.name;
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref this.name, value, true);

            ClearErrors();
            SetProperty(ref this.name, value);
            ValidateAllProperties();
            OnPropertyChanged("ErrorDictionary[Name]");
        }
    }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(4096)]
    public string WebImageLink
    {
        get => this.webImageLink;
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref this.webImageLink, value, true);

            ClearErrors();
            ValidateAllProperties();
            OnPropertyChanged("ErrorDictionary[WebImageLink]");
        }
    }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(255)]
    [MinLength(2)]
    public string Club
    {
        get => this.club;
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref this.club, value, true);

            ClearErrors();
            ValidateAllProperties();
            OnPropertyChanged("ErrorDictionary[Club]");
        }
    }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(32)]
    public string Birthday
    {
        get => this.birthday;
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref this.birthday, value, true);

            ClearErrors();
            ValidateAllProperties();
            OnPropertyChanged("ErrorDictionary[Birthday]");
        }
    }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string BirthPlace
    {
        get => this.birthPlace;
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref this.birthPlace, value, true);

            ClearErrors();
            ValidateAllProperties();
            OnPropertyChanged("ErrorDictionary[BirthPlace]");
        }
    }

    [Required]
    [Range(0, 100)]
    public int? Weight
    {
        get => this.weight;
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref this.weight, value, true);

            ClearErrors();
            ValidateAllProperties();
            OnPropertyChanged("ErrorDictionary[Weight]");
        }
    }

    [Required]
    [Range(0, 2.5)]
    public double? Height
    {
        get => this.height;
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref this.height, value, true);

            ClearErrors();
            ValidateAllProperties();
            OnPropertyChanged("ErrorDictionary[Height]");
        }
    }

    [Required]
    public string Description
    {
        get => this.description;
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref this.description, value, true);

            ClearErrors();
            ValidateAllProperties();
            OnPropertyChanged("ErrorDictionary[Description]");
        }
    }

    [Required]
    public PositionModel Position
    {
        get => this.position;
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref this.position, value, true);

            ClearErrors();
            ValidateAllProperties();
            OnPropertyChanged("ErrorDictionary[Name]");
        }
    }

    public PlayerModel() : base()
    {}

    public PlayerModel(int id, string name, string webImageLink, string club, string birthday, string birthPlace, int weight, double height, string description, string positionName, int positionId) : base()
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
        WebImageLink = webImageLink;
        Club = club;
        Birthday = birthday;
        BirthPlace = birthPlace;
        Weight = weight;
        Height = height;
        Description = description;
        Position = new PositionModel(positionId, positionName);
    }

    public PlayerModel(int id, string name, string webImageLink, string club, string birthday, string birthPlace, int weight, double height, string description, PositionModel position) : base()
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
        WebImageLink = webImageLink;
        Club = club;
        Birthday = birthday;
        BirthPlace = birthPlace;
        Weight = weight;
        Height = height;
        Description = description;
        Position = position;
    }

    public PlayerModel(PlayerEntity player)
    {
        Id = player.Id;
        Name = player.Name;
        WebImageLink = player.WebImageLink;
        Club = player.Club;
        Birthday = player.Birthday;
        BirthPlace = player.BirthPlace;
        Weight = player.Weight;
        Height = player.Height;
        Description = player.Description;
        Position = new PositionModel(player.Position);
    }

    public PlayerEntity ToEntity()
    {
        return new PlayerEntity
        {
            Id = Id,
            Name = Name,
            WebImageLink = WebImageLink,
            Club = Club,
            Birthday = Birthday,
            BirthPlace = BirthPlace,
            Weight = Weight.Value,
            Height = Height.Value,
            Description = Description,
            PositionId = Position.Id
        };
    }

    public void ToEntity(PlayerEntity player)
    {
        player.Id = Id;
        player.Name = Name;
        player.WebImageLink = WebImageLink;
        player.Club = Club;
        player.Birthday = Birthday;
        player.BirthPlace = BirthPlace;
        player.Weight = Weight.Value;
        player.Height = Height.Value;
        player.Description = Description;

        player.PositionId = Position.Id;
    }
}

public delegate void NotifyWithValidationMessages(Dictionary<string, string?> validationDictionary);

public class BaseViewModel : ObservableValidator
{
    public event NotifyWithValidationMessages? ValidationCompleted;

    public virtual ICommand ValidateCommand => new RelayCommand(() =>
    {
        ClearErrors();

        ValidateAllProperties();

        var validationMessages = this.GetErrors()
                                     .ToDictionary(k => k.MemberNames.First().ToLower(), v => v.ErrorMessage);

        ValidationCompleted?.Invoke(validationMessages);
    });


    [IndexerName("ErrorDictionary")]
    public ValidationStatus this[string propertyName]
    {
        get
        {
            var errors = this.GetErrors()
                             .ToDictionary(k => k.MemberNames.First(), v => v.ErrorMessage) ?? new Dictionary<string, string?>();

            var hasErrors = errors.TryGetValue(propertyName, out var error);
            return new ValidationStatus(hasErrors, error ?? string.Empty);
        }
    }

    public BaseViewModel() : base()
    {}
}

public class ValidationStatus : ObservableObject
{
    private bool hasError;
    private string error;

    public bool HasError
    {
        get => this.hasError;
        set => SetProperty(ref this.hasError, value);
    }

    public string Error
    {
        get => this.error;
        set => SetProperty(ref this.error, value);
    }

    public ValidationStatus()
    {
    }

    public ValidationStatus(bool hasError, string error)
    {
        this.hasError = hasError;
        this.error = error;
    }
}

public class PositionModel
{
    [Required]
    [Range(1, 7)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public PositionModel()
    {
    }

    public PositionModel(int id, string name)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
    }

    public PositionModel(PositionEntity entity)
    { 
        Id = entity.Id;
        Name = entity.Name;
    }

    public PositionEntity ToEntity()
    {
        return new PositionEntity
        {
            Id = Id,
            Name = Name
        };
    }

    public void ToEntity(PositionEntity entity)
    {
        entity.Id = Id;
        entity.Name = Name;
    }
```

What is very interesting, if I edit the first object everything works as it, but if I navigate on the second object and try to edit it, the position is not set. And so on, the third object will have set the position, the 4th won't, and so on.
Any idea?

Comment: Where's `player` defined and why are you setting the `BindingContext` in `OnAppearing()`? Also, where's the "Update Page" you're referring to? Please show all relevant parts of your code.

Comment: You are also manually setting the picker values and then setting the BindingContext, which will likely override the values you just set.  If you are using data binding you should not also set values manually

Comment: @Jason I tried without setting the picker selected index, but not worked. I saw a post where this was the suggested way, but not working for me.

Comment: @ewerspej I updated the question, and posted all the code, as it was originaly

Comment: first, set the BindingContext in the constructor and see if that helps

Comment: You should consider using the MVVM pattern. You have a lot of logic in your View code. Business logic belongs into separate, maintainable classes, which makes debugging, testing and development a lot easier and less error-prone.

Comment: @Jason not helped, that way the controls are empty.

Comment: you are also setting the BindingContext in BOTH the XAML and the code behind.  This is a problem.

Comment: @Jason I disagree.

Comment: Show declaration of `PlayerModel` class, and its `Name` property. I assume you've verified ItemsSource is being set to a list that contains at least one item? Consider a test where you set ItemsSource **in the constructor** (after InitializeComponent) to a "hardcoded" list with a single Player, whose Name is set. Reason: I'm suspecting there is some problem with the order in which things are done. Want to know if the picker behaves correctly if the information is available much earlier.

Comment: `SelectedItem="{Binding Position}">`. Show declaration of `Position`. When are you expecting the "previous value" to be shown? You mean after user picks one? Any warnings in VS Output Pane, that mention `Position` or `Name`?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve The previous value for position is coming as a part of the query property, and the picker is not showing the value for it.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I added the asked models

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve The picker ItemSource is populated as it should be.

Comment: *"The picker ItemSource is populated as it should be"* I understand. What I'm speculating is that maybe there is a Maui bug where the value is not displayed unless the itemSource is populated EARLIER. I could be totally off-base, but populating it **in the constructor** would tell us whether this is an issue or not.

Comment: *"And so on, the third object will have set the position, the 4th won't, and so on"* - **1)**  Does the position not get **set** in the item, OR is it just not **displayed** in the picker? **2)** If you edit them in a different order, does that change which ones "work"? Is it always "works, then not work, works, then not work", regardless of which you pick? **3)** Anyway, sounds like confirmation that there is some Maui bug re updating the displayed value.

Comment: `OnPropertyChanged("ErrorDictionary[WebImageLink]");`. I've never seen a syntax like that string `"ErrorDictionary[WebImageLink]"`. **1)** **Please give link to relevant doc.** All I've ever seen is`"WebImageLink"` or `nameof(WebImageLink)`. OR simply leave off the parameter: it is not needed unless one property is dependent on another property. **2)** **Does it work better if** you change all those to simply `OnPropertyChanged();`?

Comment: What's the code of `ObservableValidator`,`PositionEntity `, `ClearErrors();`  and `ValidateAllProperties();`?  If it is convenient for you, could you please post a basic demo so that we can test on our side?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve it was interesting while I do the debug. The Position in the player are received, and when setting the BindingContext, the Position property is set to null.
Editing in the different order, doesn't change anything.
My suggestion is that the Picker cant find the SelectedItem int he ItemSource for some reason.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Please  visit the following answers
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74956610/net-maui-entry-behaviors-and-triggers-on-validation-not-triggers/74961564#74961564

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve ObservableValidator cames form CommunityToolkit.Mvvm package

Answer (score 1):

At the end, I finally come up with a solution. The Position class has to implement IEquatable interface, then the Picker finds the binded Position object from the ViewModel.

```
public bool Equals(PositionModel? position) => this.Id == position?.Id &&
                                               this.Name == position?.Name;
```

Another solution was, as I mentioned in my comment:
,, *If we want the Picker to bind to a property of object type, it needs to come from the same collection as the Pickers ItemSource. I have a feeling, that it looks equality on a ,,reference,, type.* ,,

Comment: FYI: `OnPropertyChanged("player");` is a bug. xamarin is NOT being told when `Player property` changes. Should be `OnPropertyChanged("Player");` OR `OnPropertyChanged();` OR `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Player));`  I don't know whether fixing that would have helped or not, but you should make that change in case it affects something else in the future.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

Ok, I misunderstood the binding. I think x:Name ViewModel is interfering with BindingContext = player.

- Remove BindingContext from xaml.
- Do that in constructor instead: BindingContext = new PlayerModel().
- Then the later set of BindingContext should work as expected.

———————

**Original answer; Wrong explanation**

- `Position` is a property *on each Player*.
- `Picker` is *on the page*.
- `<Picker x:Name="position" SelectedItem="{Binding Position}">` is looking for a property `Position` *on the page*. Looks like there is no such property.

It won't magically find Position on a player.

I see page has `Player` property. Assuming that is always the correct player to look at, then bind to `Player.Position`. I'm not sure what happens if Player is null.

Try:
  `<Picker x:Name="position" SelectedItem="{Binding Player.Position}">`.

Comment: Ok, I will try. But the BindingContext is set to a player variable, but I think you got the point, have sense what you wrote. Let you know.;

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood the binding. My explanation is wrong. x:Name ViewModel is interfering with BindingContext = player. Remove BindingContext from xaml. Do that in constructor instead.

Comment: I tried, because I was out of idea, but not worked.

Comment: At the end I figured out. I think the MAUI Picker has a bug. If we want Picker to bind to a property of object type, it needs to come from the same collection as the Pickers ItemSource. I have a feeling, that it looks equality on a ,,reference,, type. Another idea is to implement the IEquatable<T> Interface on the Position class.